# Strange Registry Access Exception

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to change certain value in the registry programmatically (C#) but I am constantly running into Unauthorized-Access-Exceptions.

The registry-keys that I am trying to modify have been created by a driver-installer for an USB-audio-Device. This device (a LogiLink USB Sound Box 7.1) sometimes “forgets” its settings and I am looking for a quick way to re-set the settings automatically.

Reading the values with the usual Microsoft.Win32.Registry-methods is no problem, but trying to overwrite certain values seems to be difficult.

However, doing the changes manually (using regedit) is no problem. I do have admin rights as a User and I am starting all my C# programs that ought to modify the values “as Administrator”, but to no avail.

Here are a few things I have tried:

-Giving my application Admin-rights in the app.manifest.

-Tring to open the Key with the Microsoft.Win32-methods with the writable = true. Here I get an System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

```
RegistryKey key =
               RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
               RegistryView.Registry64);
            key = key.OpenSubKey(regPath,true);
```

-Exporting the key into a *.reg-file using reg. (always works)

```
String strCmdText = "/C REG EXPORT <KeyPath> <ExportPath> /reg:64";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Then I can modify the resulting file and try to import it using various methods.

```
String strCmdText = "/C REG IMPORT <PathToReg> /reg:64";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Or

```
String strCmdText = <PathToReg>;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("REGEDIT.exe", strCmdText);
```

I tried those methods in other places in the registry and they work flawlessly, however they fail if I want to apply them to the keys of the USB-audio-Device. The Processes always end with return-code 0.

Manually importing the exported and modified *.reg-file always works and the Device-Settings are changed as expected. Even using the CMD-Console manually yields the desired result.  However, if I try to do the exact same thing in C#, no change is happening (even with admin-rights).

I would be very glad if someone had an idea about this. Thank you.

Comment: Long shot, could it be your antivirus? or Windows Defender? Some antivirus products can block access to registry if you access certain places in HKLM and is not regedit or some other known app.

Comment: @Madushan I deactivated my antivirus and Windows Defender. But there is no notable change.